# How to check if a Mac application was started via .app or executable

Tags: c++, macos, bundle

I have a C++ application which I redistribute in a Mac OS Bundle. How can I check in code if my app was started by opening the `MyApp.app`-bundle or by executing `MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp`?

I tried this:

```
#include "CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h"

CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
CFURLRef resourcesURL = CFBundleCopyBundleURL(mainBundle);
CFStringRef str = CFURLCopyFileSystemPath( resourcesURL, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle );
CFRelease(resourcesURL);
char* path = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1024);

CFStringGetCString( str, path, FILENAME_MAX, kCFStringEncodingASCII );
CFRelease(str);
printf("NS: %s\n", path);
```

Which always gives me the path to `MyApp.app`. And I tried this:

```
#include <mach-o/dyld.h>

char pathbuf[PATH_MAX + 1];
char real_executable[PATH_MAX + 1];
char *bundle_id;
uint32_t  bufsize = sizeof(pathbuf);

_NSGetExecutablePath( pathbuf, &bufsize);
printf("NS: %s\n", pathbuf);
```

Which always prints the path to the executable.

Comment: argv[0] contains the full path of your app if it's started by the Finder, but it's not a very nice way to check that since you can just start the app like that yourself...

Comment: Running the app bundle **is** running the executable. There may be differences in the environment that's inherited, although some of those differences would also be present if the user uses `/usr/bin/open` to open the app bundle from a shell. What are you really trying to accomplish? Why do you care? Perhaps the most reliable technique would be to have the user specify a command-line option if they want a different mode.

Comment: Because the working directory of the application is different when launching in different ways I wanted to set some paths but I already found a workaround.